# Calling async function in .map() (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, mapping

I'm trying to iterate over IDs (**track.id**) and for each of them fetch some data (based on those IDs) from API (**getBPM()**). I'm pretty sure it's connected with Promises and I'm not very fluent with these yet.
Here's the code:

```
const getBpm = async (id) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features", {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        params: {
            ids: id,
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
    return Math.round(data[0]?.audio_features[0].tempo);
}

function renderTracks() {
        return tracks?.map((track) => 
            <li key={track.id} className="song-item">
                <a className='link-to-song' href="">
                    <div className="img-with-data">
                    <img src={track.album.images[0].url} alt="" />
                        <div className="title-artist">
                            <p className='song-title'>{track.name}</p>
                            <p className='song-artist'>{track.artists[0].name}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p className="tempo">{getBpm(track.id)}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        )
}
```

I've tried some things, but couldn't get it to work. I'd appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call an async function you have to await the the function like `await getBpm(track.id)`. Ideally you shouldn't fetch the data in the return statement. the spotify API allows you to fetch multiple tracks on each request. https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-audio-features-several-tracks/ I would do something like

```
const songIds = tracks.map(track => track.id).join(","); // songIds should be a string of track ID's separated by a comma (if my code errors, you know what to do)
const trackDataFromApi = await getBpm(songIds); // This will give you data for all your songs
```

Then you might want to merge your 2 data sets. And add your tempo-data to your `tracks`-variable.

And your function.

```
const getBpm = async (ids) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features", {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        params: {
            ids: ids, // or just ids for shorthand
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
    return data;
}
```